# Why wolfram cannot get the third solution?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B3x-4%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B5-3x%7D%3D1

This surely has the third solution as x= 13/3.

But:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D%3D13%2F3%2C+%5Csqrt%7B3x-4%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B5-3x%7D-1

Why Wolfram fails to get it correct?

Comment: You do know that $-1$ isn't the only value associated with $\sqrt[3]{-1}$? In fact, when the latter is written, it almost always doesn't mean $-1$.

Comment: I expect it is confused as to which branch of the cube root you intend.  I specified the real-valued root and it found the third root with no problem.

Comment: yes $$\sqrt[3]{-1}$$ means three things but it surely can mean one thing of the three and satisfies the equation, but why wolfram still fails to get it?

Comment: @BradyZeng because it works with principal root, unless instructed otherwise. Although if you use 1/3 instead of sqrt[3], it "magically" gives you the option of using the real root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wolfram Language function `Power[]` ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html)) gives the principal root, meaning the one with the least complex angle.  For example, [\sqrt[3]{-8}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B-8%7D), which gives $1 + \mathrm{i}\sqrt{3}$, having angle $\pi/3$, instead of $-2$, having angle $\pi$.  We can see that the complex angle of $\sqrt[3]{5-3x}$ changes between 1.6 and 1.7.

WA: [plot (5 - 3 x)^(1/3) and Arg((5 - 3 x)^(1/3)) for 0<=x<=5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%285%20-%203%20x%29%5E%281%2F3%29%20and%20Arg%28%285%20-%203%20x%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%20for%200%3C%3Dx%3C%3D5)

in exactly the same way the result of `Power[]` does.

WA: [plot Power[5 - 3 x,1/3] and Arg(Power[5 - 3 x,1/3]) for 0<=x<=5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Power%5B5%20-%203%20x%2C1%2F3%5D%20and%20Arg%28Power%5B5%20-%203%20x%2C1%2F3%5D%29%20for%200%3C%3Dx%3C%3D5)

Methods to avoid this

- Use a function that always returns the real root, like `CubeRoot[]` ([doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CubeRoot.html)).  [\sqrt{3x-4}+CubeRoot[5-3x]=1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B3x-4%7D%2BCubeRoot%5B5-3x%5D%3D1).  Also `cbrt()` is a WA shortcut for this function.
- Use a form for which WA explicitly mentions that it is assuming a root, then tell it which assumption you actually want.  [\sqrt{3x-4}+(5-3x)^(1/3)=1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B3x-4%7D%2B%285-3x%29%5E%281%2F3%29%3D1%20) , then click "the real-valued root instead".
- More generally than using `CubeRoot[]`, there is `surd()` ([docs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Surd.html)), which also gives the real root, when there is one.  So here, we would use [\sqrt{3x-4}+surd(5-3x,3)=1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B3x-4%7D%2Bsurd%285-3x%2C3%29%3D1)

Comment: This is very detailed explanation. Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Because it assumes the principal cube root. If you add the assumption that the root is the real root, it gives you all the solutions like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B3x-4%7D%2B(5-3x)%5E(1%2F3)%3D1&assumption="%5E"+->+"Real").

Comment: I see. \sqrt[3]{} is different to ^(1/3) in wolfram.